# window function parenthesis error on MYSQL8.0.11

Tags: mysql, window, mysql-workbench, ddl, partition

I've working on MYSQL 8.0.11 and testing window functions but getting what I think is an unexpected error via workbench.

```
SELECT AVG(Volume) OVER(PARTITION BY `Security` ORDER BY DateValue ROWS 19 PRECEDING) AS MAV20
FROM t_EOD_Dly;
```

In workbenches query window at the `Over(` I am getting `Syntax error: Unexpected '(' (opening parenthesis)`

To my best knowledge, brackets are correct. The SQL statement executes correctly with a green tick in the output window.

Interestingly when I drop the same SQL into a stored procedure it won't apply and generates `The object's DDL statement contains syntax errors.` when attempting to do so.

Is this a bug in build 8.0.11 or am i missing something really simple?

Comment: You may try to put a space between `OVER` and `(`. Though omitting the space is not strictly an error, I guess, maybe that confuses it. But that's just a wild guess...

Comment: I had tried `OVER (` didn't make a difference unfortunately

Comment: this version with 2 window functions produces the error on the first OVER (` but not the 2nd.  `SELECT min(Volume) OVER (PARTITION BY `Security`) AS MAV20, min(Volume) OVER (PARTITION BY `Security`) AS MAV30
FROM t_EOD_Dly;`.  n.b. the reserverd word Security has backticks, i just can't get them to show in this comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This morning i upgraded both Server and Workbench to 8.0.12 and windows functions now work and I can save to stored procedure.